# keep session data in a System.Web.Services.WebService's WebMethod

Tags: asp.net, web-services, session, webmethod

I'm using VS2010, asp.net c#.

I have a WebMethod declared like this

```
      [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public String getErrorMsg()
        {           
if (HttpContext.Current.Session["error"] == null) return "empty";
else return ((String)(HttpContext.Current.Session["error"]));
        }
```

Inside a System.Web.Services.WebService Class(inheritaded).

In another WebMethod, I set this message let's just assume it's like this

```
   [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
            public void firstMethod()
            {           
    HttpContext.Current.Session["error"] ="bla";
}
```

In another project, I have added a Service Refrence to this WebService.
I then try to use it like this:

```
    WebService1.WebService1SoapClient MyService=
    new WebService1.WebService1SoapClient();
        MyService.firstMethod(); // this calls the method that sets
 //the "bla" string in the session
    String str=MyService.getErrorMsg();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Message "+str);
```

Str is "empty";

At the first method, the "bla" string is set to the session. as long as im in this method, i can use the session stored data.
When I make another call to the WebService, the previous session data is no longer exists.

Ive looked everywhere. I found only this example :

```
 // instantiate the proxy 
    localhost.MyDemo MyService = new localhost.MyDemo();

    // create a container for the SessionID cookie
    MyService.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

    // call the Web Service function
    Label1.Text += MyService.HelloWorld() + "<br />";
```

But there is 2 main problems:

1) My WebService cannot be used as an object, meaning I cannot use "new" on that class, as this example somehow does.

I use WebService1SoapClient in order to use the WebService.

2)There is no such thing CookieContainer in the WebService1SoapClient object.

I think this example must have been used in an old vs/.net version.

Does anyone knows how can I keep a Session data in a webService?

Comment: Are you using "Add Service Reference", or "Add Web Reference"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might seems to find the answer.
In web.config you have a

```
     <system.serviceModel>
            <bindings>
              <basicHttpBinding>
 <binding name="NameOfWebServiceSoap"/>
         </basicHttpBinding>
            </bindings>
           <client>
              <endpoint address="*AddressOfWebService*" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="*NameOfWebServiceSoap*" 
    contract="*NameOfWebService.NameOfWebServiceSoap*" name="*NameOfServiceReference*"/>
            </client>
          </system.serviceModel>
```

Add the following under the binding name:

```
allowCookies="true"
```

So it looks like this:

```
<binding name="NameOfWebServiceSoap" allowCookies="true"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would have to think that you are mistaken for 2 reasons

1. You are using *new* on your webservice proxy class

   > WebService1.WebService1SoapClient MyService=
   >       **new** WebService1.WebService1SoapClient();
2. Any webservice proxy you create with visual studio inherits from `System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol` which implements CookieContainer()

Comment: You see you are wrong now. Im not making a new WebService1 object but a new WebService1SoapClient object, which is a completley different class. And how can I set the CookieContainer to this class? If you know how please share a code

Comment: Webservice1 is the namespace - WebService1SoapClient is the actual object you are creating

Comment: Lets try something - add a check to the code to see if its a httwe whaterver

if (myservice is System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol)
{ console.WriteLine("Yes") } else {console.writeline("No")}

If it is then it would be weird that you can't access the CookieContainer

If it isn't then I obviously stand corrected and i suggest that you try to recreate the web reference

Comment: Oh - i forgot to ask - is this a webservice or a WCF client?